# jQuery - input changeclass and value to fontawesome

Tags: jquery, laravel

I want my input on submit to change to loading state.

```
$('.waves-button-input').prop('disabled', true).val('&#xf110').removeClass('waves-button-input').addClass('fas fa-spinner fa-spin');
```

This will output `&#xf110` on the input value, even with the fas class added.
But when I manually edit the HTML in chrome, the icon is shown (but not when the input is already clicked)

My html(blade):

```
{!! Form::submit('Yes', ['class' => 'waves-effect waves-light btn green']) !!}
```

Blade html output:

```
<i class="align-center btn btn-small waves-effect waves-light waves-input-wrapper" style="">
<input class="waves-button-input" type="submit" value="SUBMIT">
</i>
```

I'm aware that I can use `<button>`, but I'd like to see this work so I don't have to change all my inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you could do is to hide then button on submit and then added a spinner just after it with something like:

```
$("input[type=submit]").hide();
var spinner = $('<i class="fas fa-spinner fa-spin"></i>').insertAfter("input[type=submit]");
```

Then to bring the input back in you could have something like:

```
spinner.remove();
$("input[type=submit]").show();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

```js
$(function(){
  $('.waves-button').on('click', function(e){
    $(this)
        .prop('disabled', 'disabled')
        .find('.btn-text').hide()
        .siblings('.loader').show();
  });
});
```

```html
<button class="waves-button">
  <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin loader" style="display:none"></i>
  <span class="btn-text">Send</span>
</button>
```

Comment: As per the last comment to the OP's post, they want to try and avoid using buttons.